# Latex whole document is centered

Tags: luatex, overleaf

I am writing my Thesis in Latex. I think I have done something wrong and now the whole document is aligned centered. There are bunch of packages that I have included in my preamble, so it is hard to post a MWE. Any idea why this happens? Or how do I ask this question better?
[image]

Comment: No error during the LaTeX run?

Comment: no error, just the whole document is aligned centered

Comment: Then you have a stray `\centering` command somewhere.

Comment: you are just showing the table of contents which doesn't really look centred, do you mean that the main text you haven't shown are centred?  You should be able to make a small one page document that shows the problem.

Comment: If it's hard for you to post a MWE then it's even harder for us to find out the issue... in the process of making a MWE you should be able to determine the error yourself (alternatively bisect through history, if you keep the history)